# jquery submit form how to make other page

Tags: php, jquery

When I query from a page, I submit the form with jquery in sorgu.php. but how do i do it without making it infinite loop?
is there any other way ?
page [link](https://tunga.muhammetkorkut.com/smm/)
header.php code search mod

```
<div class="modal fade" id="srcModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contacthModal">
<div class="row searchArea modal-dialog modal-content" role="document">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row searchCloserow">
            <div class="closeBtn"  data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kapat </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row searchForm d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-2 searchText">
                <span id="myModalLabel">Sipariş Sorgulama Ekranı</span>
                <p>Sorgulamak istediğiniz siparişin kodunu giriniz!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 searchwell">
                <input type="text" name="siparis_key"  id="siparis_key" placeholder="Lütfen Sipariş Kodunu Giriniz">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="sorgu"  id="siparis_Sorgula" type="submit" class="searchbtn anibut">
                    Sipariş Sorgula <i class="fas fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and header.php jquery code. here i am changing the href href="sorgu?key=asdasdasd"

```
 $("#siparis_Sorgula").click(function(){

    $data = $('#siparis_key').val();
    $href = $("#siparis_Sorgula").attr('href');
    $href = $href+"?key="+$data;
    $("#siparis_Sorgula").attr("href", $href);

});
```

sorgu.php page code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="jsSorgula">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="siparis_key" id="siparis_keyId" placeholder="<?php echo $dil['sipariskodu'] ?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><?php echo $dil['sorgula'] ?></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

sorgu.php jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
    return vars;
}


$count = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    if ($count==0) {
        $keys = getUrlVars()["key"];
        $('#siparis_keyId').val($keys);

        $("#jsSorgula").submit();
        $count++;
        alert($count);

    }
    break;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinity loop could came from your `$count = 0`. Is set to 0 each time you make a request on that page. Instead of make the validation with count == 0, you should use a method like "on click" or "on change".